# How do I create and cache a DOM element that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, assert

I'm writing an assert function.  How do I cache #assert if it doesn't exist yet?

```
function assert( outcome, description ) {
   if (!$('#assert').length) {
      $('body').append('<ul id="assert"></ul>');
   }
   $('#assert').append('<li class="' + (outcome ? 'hide' : 'alert-danger') + '">' + description + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that jsLint is going to complain that I'm referencing $('#assert') twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this...

```
function assert( outcome, description ) {
    var assrt = $('#assert');
    if (!assrt || !assrt.length) {
        assrt = $('<ul>',{id:"assert"}).appendTo('body');
    }
    assrt.append('<li>', {className:outcome ? 'hide' : 'alert-danger', text:description});
}
```

---

Or if the `assert` element is meant to be used by subsequent invocations, I'd probably use a closure to maintain a reference between calls...

```
var assert = (function() {
    var assrt = $('#assert');

    return function( outcome, description )
        if (!assrt || !assrt.length) {
            assrt = $('<ul>',{id:"assert"}).appendTo('body');
        }
        assrt.append('<li>', {className:outcome ? 'hide' : 'alert-danger', text:description});
    };
}());
```

---

You could expand on this by returning several functions...

```
var assert = (function() {
    var assrt = $('#assert');

    function verify_assert_container() {
        if (!assrt || !assrt.length) {
            assrt = $('<ul>',{id:"assert"}).appendTo('body');
        }
    }

    return {
        add: function( outcome, description )
            verify_assert_container();
            assrt.append('<li>', {className:outcome ? 'hide' : 'alert-danger', text:description});
        },
        empty: function() {
            verify_assert_container();
            assrt.empty();
        },
        sort: function() {
            verify_assert_container();
            // use sorting algorithm to reorder the LI elements
        },
        destroy: function() {
            if (assrt) {
                assrt.remove();
                assrt = null;
            }
        }
    };
}());
```

and use it like this...

```
assert.add('foo', 'bar');
assert.empty();
assert.destroy();
```

Comment: Wow.  This is a very good piece of code.  This gives me a good example of when to use a closure.

Comment: @Pedro: If you like that closure idea, I added another example that returns several functions in an object, all of which operate on the closed variable, as well as a reusable function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$assert = $('<ul id="assert"></ul>');
$('body').append($assert);
```

Note that I did not declare `$assert` with the `var` keyword, thus giving it global scope (in case you wanted it elsewhere). If you only need it scoped to your assert function, use `var`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
 div = $("<div>").attr("id", "assert")
```